# В json_encode() свойство есть, а в объекте нет. Как такое может быть?

Tags: php, массивы, laravel

Вот такой код у меня во `View`.

```
        @forelse ($questions as $question)
            <a href="#" class="list-group-item">
                <h4>{{$question->title}}</h4>
                <p>{{Str::limit($question->body, 100)}}</p>
                <span>Asked {{$question->created}} by {{$question->user_name}}</span>
                {{json_encode($question)}}
            </a>
        @empty
            <h2>No questions!</h2>
        @endforelse
```

Тем не менее, в html после Asked нет ничего (выводится пробел. Наверное, `null`), а `json_encode` показывает, что свойство `created` там есть. То же самое с `user_name`.

Вот такой html получается (поставил '...' для наглядности):

```
<a href="#" class="list-group-item">
            <h4>...</h4>
            <p>...</p>
            <span>Asked  by </span> 
            <br>
            {"id":1,"title":"...","path":"...","body":"...","created":"2 hours ago","user_name":"Nash Bogisich","user_id":11}
        </a>
```

Такая простая проверка показала, что `created == null`

```
if ($question->created==null){
                        $created = 'null value';
                    }
```

Comment: Если вы решили свой вопрос - можете написать ответ.

Comment: @u_mulder, не решил. Написал на англоязычном, вообще никакой активности. Посмотрю еще раз утром,может, все проще чем кажется.

Comment: А в чем вопрос-то?

Comment: @u_mulder, мне нужно эти данные отобразить в view. Данные у меня какие-то странные. Вопрос в заголовке. Я хочу отобразить объект, он какой-то не целый.

Comment: Мне кажется у Вас не объект вовсе. Мне кажется у Вас вовсе даже и массив. json_encode() очень мило преобразовывает ассоциативные массивы в объекты. Замените ````{{json_encode($question)}}```` на ````{{var_export($question, true)}}```` и посмотрите что получилось на экране.

Comment: А еще лучше посмотрите свой объект используя @php(dump($question))

Comment: `dd($question)` посмотрите что покажет